# docker compose "failed to solve: rpc error: code"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using this little `docker-compose.yaml` file to start two containers in an EC2 to start a preview of my app:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis:
      build:
        context: .
      ports:
        - 6379:6379
  database:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14.2
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
volumes:
  postgres:
```

The redis image is build from a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM redis:alpine

COPY ./redis.conf /etc/redis.conf

CMD ["redis-server", "/etc/redis.conf"]
```

Now when I run `docker compose up -d` I get the following error:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/redis:alpine   0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/redis:alpine:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown 
desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: 
failed to create LLB definition: 
failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown 
desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: 
Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fredis%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": 
dial tcp: lookup auth.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:58421->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

But if I run `docker image build -t .` and then rerun `docker compose up -d` all works.

I searched online a bit about the error, but I didn't find any useful.

I find here on stack overflow that there are a bunch of questions with the same `failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown`, but the body of the error is different.

The compose file works perfectly on my local machine.